# Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication), when ever integrating react native in to existing apps

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-layout

Hi I want to embed the React native screen in to my Android native screen..
I tried with index.js file in my android native as below code... Every time getting same issue..

```
    var mReactRootView = ReactRootView(this);
    var  mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setCurrentActivity(this)
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index.js")
            .addPackage(MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.BEFORE_CREATE)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "sample", null);
    rl_webImage.removeAllViews()
    rl_webImage.addView(mReactRootView)  // this is android layout xml
```